# Invalid probabilities in xgboost in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, xgboost

I'm using xgboost in spark (scala api). I'm training my model using the following parameters:

```
val params = List("eta" -> "0.1", "max_depth" -> "2", 
                  "silent" -> "1", "objective" -> "binary:logistic").toMap 
XGBoost.train(trainRDD, params, 10, 10)
```

Then it provides two `predict` functions for scoring. One which take a `DMatrix` and operates in the driver (locally) and one which takes an `RDD[Vector]` and operates in a distributed mode.

For the same test data set, these two functions return different values: the one which operates locally returns values which are like -1.23 or 1.34, but the other one returns 0.21 or 0.71. It looks like the second one returns the probabilities which are between 0 and 1, but the first one returns something else.

Could someone elaborate on this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. The `predict` function which operates locally output margin values. That means, we need to apply the logistic transformation on those values in order to get the probabilities.